# Could I have the list of current moderators?

Tags: support, moderators

Who are the current moderators on Japanese StackExchange?

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of moderators [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators); it's part of the 'Users' menu every Stack Exchange site has.

(I'm not sure if it's useful to list them here, as that list would have to be updated manually in case there are changes.)